# Starting Tomcat in Eclipse results in an error like "source name, file name, label name is invalid"

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm using Eclipse IDE and Tomcat 7 to build a Java EE application.

When I launch Tomcat in any Eclipse IDE it gives me an error like **"source name, file name, label name is invalid & open one notepad in eclipse"**. I even uninstalled and re-installed everything, but it still gives me this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: How your are creating your Server in Eclipse..

Comment: Window -> preference -> server like that only.

Comment: Everytime whenever you were creating the Server, Its just creates an Instance. First delete all of them, then create the new one.

Comment: I uninstalled everything completely including JDK. and I installed back Jdk and eclipse and tomcat and start configuring new.. At that time also i'm getting the same error. sometimes i deleted some registry key also.. But i couldn't find the proper solution'

Comment: Do i have problem with my OS? If anybody knows tell me

Comment: What's the exact error text? Is it in a popup dialog or the Console view?

Comment: Not in Console view.. It gives popup. while starting tomcat, Notepad window automatically opening and with popup.

Comment: That error message looks made-up: "label name is invalid & open one notepad in eclipse"? Can you copy/paste the actual error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found answer for my question.

I just configured for running browser as my default browser that is Chrome web browser. While starting **apache tomcat 6.0** server in eclipse default i had mentioned my chrome web browser because of that i have got error with pop windows..

I just make a change browser settings into eclipse internal web browser. While starting tomcat now It wont give any error. A bit surprise for mozilla also It wont give any error.

I'm back to work on Java EE.